# Nested y axis with faced wrap x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, facet-wrap

I want to plot the following dataset to visualize all measurements done or missing:

```
data<- read.table(text = "Sample_ID Species Time Treatment
    Amu1 Amu   1  A
    Amu1 Amu   2  A
    Amu1 Amu   3  A
    Amu5 Amu   1  B
    Amu5 Amu   2  B
    Amu2 Amu   1  A
    Amu2 Amu   2  A
    Amu2 Amu   3  A
    Amu3 Amu   1  A
    Amu3 Amu   2  A
    Amu4 Amu   1  A
    Amu4 Amu   2  A
    Amu4 Amu   3  A
    Amu6 Amu   1  B
    Amu6 Amu   3  B
    Spi1 Spi   1  A
    Spi1 Spi   2  A
    Spi1 Spi   3  A
    Spi4 Spi   1  B
    Spi4 Spi   2  B
    Spi4 Spi   3  B
    Spi2 Spi   2  A
    Spi2 Spi   3  A
    Spi3 Spi   1  A
    Spi3 Spi   2  A
    Spi3 Spi   3  A
    Spi5 Spi   2  B
    Spi5 Spi   3  B
    Gfa5 Gfa   1  B
    Gfa5 Gfa   2  B
    Gfa5 Gfa   3  B
    
    ", header = TRUE)
```

Using ggplot and facet_wrap, I managed to get this plot, but I would like to nest the y-axis by species to have a visual alignment of species. The exact Sample_ID is not very important, what is really important is the number of sample_ID per treatment. For instance, In treatment A, there are 4 Amu, while in B, only 2.
However, it would be great if the space between the sample_ID on the Y-axis is always the same. Ideally, for Amu, I would like to see 4 "lines"  in treatment A while 2 in treatment B, followed by two empty lines.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
ggplot(data = data, 
       aes(x = as.factor(Time), y = fct_rev(Sample_ID),
           color = Species))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("t1", "t2", "t3"))+
  geom_point(size = 3, show.legend = F) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw() +

  facet_wrap(~ Treatment,
             scales = "free_y",
             strip.position = "top",
             ncol = 3 ) +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(color = "transparent", fill = "white"),
    axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but the trick may be using the `ggh4x` library.

```
library(ggh4x)
ggplot(data = data, 
       aes(x = as.factor(Time), y = fct_rev(interaction(Sample_ID, Species)), # use interaction to specific the grouping variable
           color = Species))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("t1", "t2", "t3"))+
  geom_point(size = 3, show.legend = F) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw() +

  facet_wrap(~ Treatment,
             scales = "free_y",
             strip.position = "top",
             ncol = 3 ) +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(color = "transparent", fill = "white"),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  guides(y = "axis_nested") ## added here with the package library(ggh4x)
```